# Linux/Laravel - How to share uploads from different projects (same server) and show them on 1 subdomain?

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have a rather complex (Laravel) project so stick with me a little bit:

I'm developing 1 Laravel app, but this app will be duplicated 13 times (each one on it's own domain, but same physical server).

All 13 apps will use the **same database**. But they all have **separate** upload directories (.../app1/public, .../app2/public).

Now what I need is for all 13 apps **to share** the uploaded files as well. I have complete access to the server set up and Laravel app, so there's plenty of ways to do this. I'm wondering what would be the best option. I can choose between nginx and apache.

I've come up with next 3 possibilities:

- Upload all files to same folder and create a fake "cdn" on the server form that folder. Let's say it's domain is cdn.app1.com. Then call all the images like that: `cdn.app1.com/path/saved/in/db.jpg` (even from app2-13.com).
- Upload all files to it's own public folder and create symlink from these folders to a fake "cdn". So same as option 1, but the files would be physically in their respective apps, with symlinks to "cdn".
- Save in the db, where each images was uploaded from and call it from there. Example if image1 is uploaded through app1, I always call it like this: app1.com/image1 (even from app2-13).

Out of these 3 each one has it's own downsides:

- 1 - Everything is uploaded through our internal CMS package, which does not allow for uploading to custom paths (anything outside public). I could bypass that with some shitty hacks, but not my favourite thing in the world.
- 2 - This seems perfect, but I have next to no knowledge of how symlinks work. Is that even possible? What happens when folders/files get duplicated (which definitely will happen). Say someone uploads to app1/public/img1, someone else uploads to app2/public/img1 and they both symlink to sym/link/dir/. What happens? I need the newer upload to overwrite the old one - is that possible?
- 3 - Error prone in a lot of ways. Also a lot of work to change it to this way.

Are any of these possibilities a decent solution? Can someone expand on what would happen in described symlink situation? Any other better solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2 is very very east and works perfect. It's as if the folder is inside your project(s)!

Comment: [Here's (img)](http://imgur.com/j3JP9W4) the problem I run into. I create the first symlink without any problems (and the cdn site serves the files as expected). But then I try to create another link from a duplicate and I get this error.

Comment: you should create the symlink, so the folder you are pointing **from** cannot already exist!

Comment: e.g. `ln -s ~/to ~/from`  ~/from cannot already exist

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/543516/what-is-a-failed-to-create-a-symbolic-link-file-exists-error

Answer (score 1):

> but this app will be duplicated 13 times (each one on it's own domain, but same physical server

Can't you just check what domain is the request is coming for and act accordingly instead of keeping 13 copies?

> I'm wondering what would be the best option. I can choose between nginx and apache

That's irrelevant in this case I think.

> I've come up with next 3 possibilities:

4. Create separate upload microservice that all of your other apps will be pushing uploads they receive from the user using microservice's API. That may not be best option if your uploads are massive, but if not, it shall be clean approach. That way all the job is done by said service and your app just needs to accept the user upload and push to the service, w/o bothering the rest. Said service can also expose  these files for i.e. download so when your app will need to list the files, it just ask microservice for file list and show it, w/o bothering the details.

Comment: > "Can't you just check what domain..." I've decided to duplicate them, because chances are high that at some point there will be exceptions (for some sub pages) in some of the duplicates. Right now the only difference is the .env file, but this might change (at which point I can just make a branch for this specific duplicate that needs exceptions). > "That's irrelevant.." Good to know, thought I'd mention it since I'm no expert in the field.

Comment: As for the 4. possibility. I believe I'll run into same issue as with possibility 1. - that it's not possible to tell exactly how/where to upload the image in our CMS package.

Comment: Absolutely not. You do NOT deal with microservice directly, but using i.e. JSON API over HTTP. So your app will accept uploaded file from user, keep it in own local storage and then upload to microservice and delete locally. No hacks, no crap. Clean separation

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I would create a microservice that moves the files from those duplicates to a single shared folder (our so called "cdn"). The question then is how to trigger this microservice. Cron seems hackish (there would be a delay). Laravel has some nice events that I could use (each time a file gets uploaded, it's saved to db as well - I could check for the db saves). But it would be even nicer if it was bound to the server. Something like - whenever a new file is uploaded to /this/folder, trigger this/service. Is that possible?

Comment: It does not move anything. It got no idea about your 13 apps. All that service should do is to expose API with methods that would allow your  apps to keep file data in sync w/o digging directly in DB etc. You can even ommit uploads if that's ok, so i.e. say user uploads file to app #7 and that app tells service "hey, I got file xxx.jpg under this URL". Serivce then just records that info and once i.e. app #11 asks for file list it returns all files it knows about, no matter which app really holds the physical file (so if app #7 deletes that file, it shall inform service so it can be updated).

Comment: I can't completely wrap my head around how the microservice would know where to look for, ie say, a picture. The uploads will 99% time be pictures that will be embedded in HTML with src="/path/to/file.jpg". Let's say that /path/to/file is served by the microservice. How would the microservice know where to serve the file from? It'll need to check 13 directories - and chances are 2 or more will have the file. It will then need to know which one was uploaded latest as well. I'm off for the day, I'll sleep on the problem and see if I'm any smarter tomorrow. Either way thanks a looot for the help!

Comment: It does not need to know, because the only thing it is going to do is to manage files. It's is NOT its task to show the list to end user - it will be your app (one of 13 :) that will be showing HTML or whatever. And the location of the image will come from the service. It's like network drive, Samba share or so but with different API